# What does 'it' refer to? Money or happiness?

Tags: ambiguity

[Poppy sings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fS9f6_i6v3Q):

> "If money can't buy happiness then why is it so fabulous?"

But what is "fabulous"? Is it money or is it happiness? Or is it (as I believe) ambiguous?

Does English grammar dictate one of these interpretations given no other context than the sentence alone?

Comment: Can you post more context? The natural reading is that she's referring to the money being fabulous, but the alternate is also possible - especially when factoring in poetic licence.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about English but about ideas. Maybe you should try at https://philosophy.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Mitch It is not about philosophy but whether English grammar dictates one interpretation over another.

Comment: @OleTange OK. I can buy that. But you should edit your question to be more explicitly about the ambiguity of 'it'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because song lyrics interpretations are [off-topic](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6886/informing-people-about-lyrics-interpretation-in-help-center?noredirect=1&lq=1) on this site.

Answer (score 2):

> If money can't buy happiness then why is it so fabulous?

There is no rule of English syntax preventing either "money" or "happiness" from being the antecedent of "it" in this sentence. So you're right: it is ambiguous. The interpretation must be based on the context and the contextual information that the listener has about the world.

My understanding is that syntactic ambiguity is found all over the place in the grammar of any natural language; at any rate, it's certainly ubiquitous  in English. (See "[Analyzing Sentence Structure](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html)" from *Natural Language Processing with Python,* by Steven Bird, Ewan Klein and Edward Loper.)

That said, many people seem to feel that ambiguity is a defect, and may propose or follow prescriptive "rules" about **how to use** pronouns, as opposed to the descriptive rules that linguists try to discover and explain about **how pronouns are used**. (For example, consider the fact that some people find it in some way meaningful to say that the sentence "Toni Morrison’s genius enables her to create novels that arise from and express the injustice African Americans have endured" contains an error; you can find discussion at [Wordorigins.org](http://www.wordorigins.org/index.php/site/comments/prescriptivists_corner_genitive_pronominal_antecedents/) and the *[New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2003/06/01/weekinreview/the-nation-parts-of-speech-the-bloody-crossroads-of-grammar-and-politics.html).*)

Prescriptive rules are not "grammar" in the sense that linguists use that word, but non-linguists may think of them as "grammar" because of the broad sense of that term in non-expert speech. (See "[It’s All Grammar](https://arnoldzwicky.org/2012/02/22/its-all-grammar/)" on Arnold Zwicky's blog.)

As the "Tony Morrison's" example indicates, some prescriptive "rules" can be quite obscure, and there is no consensus on a canonical, complete set of prescriptive "grammar" rules for English. I have heard that some people think there is a "rule" saying that a pronoun should always refer to the most recent noun phrase: this is mentioned (and stated to be wrong) in the article "[Antecedents - Placement of Pronouns](http://www.grammar.com/antecedents-placement-of-pronouns/)" from Grammar.com (I haven't vetted that site, so I don't know if it's a reliable source for linguistic grammar rules, or a partly prescriptivist source).

Examples from Google Books of sentences with similar structure:

1. Object of the *if*-clause corresponds to pronominal subject of the *then*-clause:

   - > If securitization does not block **renegotiation,** then why is **it** so rare?

     (*[Why Don't Lenders Renegotiate More Home Mortgages?](https://books.google.com/books?id=T55k9S1TPlYC&pg=PA20&dq=%22then%20why%20is%20it%20so%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj537_egN_WAhXB7oMKHRjTAp0Q6AEIWjAJ#v=onepage&q=%22then%20why%20is%20it%20so%22&f=false),* by Manuel Adelino, Kristopher Garardi, and Paul S. Willen)
   - > If the Bible does not clearly address **the spiritual condition of an infant**, then why does **it** matter?

     (*[The Spiritual Condition of Infants: A Biblical-Historical Survey and Systematic Proposal](https://books.google.com/books?id=hnFJAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA7&dq=%22then%20why%20does%20it%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj625Kl5ObWAhUJ_IMKHeicBGA4MhDoAQhAMAU#v=onepage&q=%22then%20why%20does%20it%22&f=false),* by Adam Harwood)
2. Subject of the *if*-clause corresponds to pronominal subject of the *then*-clause:

   - > If **silence** means doing nothing, then why is **it** so hard to practice!

     (*[Mind Realignment for Excellence: Naked Secrets for Building a Better You](https://books.google.com/books?id=pHEA6ik5wd8C&pg=PA183&dq=%22then%20why%20is%20it%20so%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjz3KmUgt_WAhUUyYMKHYd2CfY4HhDoAQgrMAE#v=onepage&q=%22then%20why%20is%20it%20so%22&f=false),* by Manzoor R. Massey)
   - > If **the blood that flows from women** can only be equated with life, then why is **it** so often equated with danger?

     (*[Sexual Paradox: Complementarity, Reproductive Conflict and Human Emergence](https://books.google.com/books?id=9YInrVSoa9cC&pg=PA133&dq=%22then%20why%20is%20it%20so%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidi4fRkN_WAhUl2oMKHcJzDqw4FBDoAQgqMAE#v=onepage&q=%22then%20why%20is%20it%20so%22&f=false),* by Christine Fielder and Chris King)
   - > So if **inflation** is costly, and we understand the main cause, then why does **it** occur?

     (*[Markets for Managers: A Managerial Economics Primer](https://books.google.com/books?id=OtNIBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA125&dq=%22then%20why%20does%20it%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXqsLU4-bWAhUHxoMKHdB_DWY4KBDoAQgrMAE#v=onepage&q=%22then%20why%20does%20it%22&f=false),* by Anthony J. Evans)

Answer (score 1):

The construct "subject can't do object" is about a defect in the subject, not a defect in the object.

Switch the order of ideas for the opposite sentiment: "If happiness can't make you any money then why is it so fabulous?"

Answer (score 0):

Poppy questions the general statement that "Money is fabulous". The argument is that if money can't buy the you happiness (which is the ultimate goal) then what is the point of having it and why is it considered fabulous ?

Comment: Please justify which English grammar rules state the ultimate goal is happiness.

Comment: @OleTange, No English grammar rules state the ultimate goal is happiness. I felt like that from the context.But as I read other answers and comments, I realized the ambiguity. Sorry for my poor interpretation.